# Do scholars blog or only prefer to publish papers?

Tags: blog

Are there scholars who blogs independently their thoughts not over papers? If so, which platform do they use?

Comment: See [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63337/pitfalls-of-academic-blogging) and [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5010/from-blog-posts-to-research-papers-successful-cases). For what it's worth, as-is, this appears to me as a very simple question, with a shopping question tacked on to boot (what platform to use). Not sure this question is currently a good fit for the site.

Comment: You might want to go to scholar,google.com, and I think you'll find that if someone really want to be taken seriously, they're going to try and publish in respected journals and not a blog.

Comment: @Hank, a lot of "serious" Journals have a blog and even a twitter account.

Comment: The answers are: A) Yes, and, B) pretty much any platform they want that makes life easy. The most-respected scholars I know of who blog regularly are probably Terry Tao and Timothy Gowers - both Fields Medalists (one of the highest awards a mathematician can receive). This completes the existence proof.

Comment: @0x90, yes many 'serious' Journals have a blog, but that wasn't the question.  The question was scholars who blog 'independently'. My feeling is that if you are a scholar who wants to be taken seriously, then publishing on your own blog does not have the same impact as if you publish in a respected journal

Comment: I think this shouldn't be asked as an either/or question. In my field of CS there are plenty of reputable scholars who publish in the most respected CS journals and conferences (FYI in CS there are some conferences that are more important than most journals) and who also blog.